# DJango CreateView not setting DB Key with Class-Based Views

Tags: python, django

I am using CreateView from DJango to save data to the DB. To do this, I am following the instructions here: [Form handling with class-based views](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing.html#model-forms)

According to my understanding, after the data is saved to the DB, the control is to be passed to a type of "success screen" - in this case, for my scenario, control is to be passed to a "details page". The details page is represented by the following URL:

```
url(r'^owner/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/contact/details/$', views.MstrstoreheadcontactDetailsView.as_view(), 
        name='owner-contact-details'),
```

Below (in the class Mstrstoreheadcontact) the "details page" is being called by the `get_absolute_url` function (which is part of the Mstrstoreheadcontact model)

## from the models.py file

```
class Mstrstoreheadcontact(models.Model):
    tenantid = models.ForeignKey('Mstrauthowner', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tenantid', blank=True, null=True)
    contactid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, default=0)
    genderid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    officephoneno = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    cellphoneno = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'MstrStoreHeadContact'

     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('masterdata:owner-contact-details', kwargs={'pk': self.contactid})
```

For me the code: `return reverse('masterdata:owner-contact-details', kwargs={'pk': self.contactid}` is supposed to take the control to the "details page" that will display the new record that has been added to the DB.

## The problem

When the code above is executed, the variable `self.contactid` is set to 0. See below:

This results in the following URL to be placed in the address bar:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/masterdata/owner/0/contact/details
```

Because of the "0", this leads to a 404 error. In the DB, the value is set - for example to 10.

> Again, the data saves to the DB JUST FINE- there is no problem with
> this part. The problem lies with what happens AFTER the data is saved
> to the DB.

[image]

Below are some entries from the urls.py file

## from the urls.py file

```
url(r'^owner/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/contact/details/$', views.MstrstoreheadcontactDetailsView.as_view(), 
        name='owner-contact-details'),

url(r'^owner/(?P<tenantid>[0-9]+)/contacts/add/$', views.MstrstoreheadcontactCreateView.as_view(),
        name='owner-contact-add'),
```

## from the views.py file

```
class MstrstoreheadcontactCreateView( CreateView ):
    model = Mstrstoreheadcontact
    fields = [ 'firstname', 'lastname', 'genderid', 'officephoneno', 'cellphoneno']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        contact = form.save(commit=False)
        contact.tenantid = Mstrauthowner.objects.get(tenantid=self.kwargs['tenantid'])
        return super(MstrstoreheadcontactCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

It seems like the code is not getting the data back from the DB properly (after the data has been saved). What can I do to fix the problem?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thank goodness for debuggers. The following changes resolved all the problems for me :-)

**views.py**

```
class MstrstoreheadcontactCreateView( CreateView ):
    model = Mstrstoreheadcontact
    fields = [ 'firstname', 'lastname', 'genderid', 'officephoneno', 'cellphoneno']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.tenantid = Mstrauthowner.objects.get(tenantid=self.kwargs['tenantid'])
        return super(MstrstoreheadcontactCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Mstrstoreheadcontact(models.Model):
    tenantid = models.ForeignKey('Mstrauthowner', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tenantid', blank=True, null=True)
    contactid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, default=0)

    [... snip ..]

       def get_absolute_url(self):
        [... snip ...]
        return reverse('masterdata:owner-contact-details', kwargs={'pk': self.tenantid.pk})
```